# I got problems in making partiontioned table in Oracle

Tags: oracle

i have to make  a table in oracle that represents a local retailer and  who  have stores in several states. Suppose he want to partition his stores into specific regions based on their location within each state,

Region Name  Location
South Florida    Miami, Orlando
North Florida    Jacksonville, Pensacola, Tampa
South Georgia    Brunswick, Waycross, Valdosta
North Georgia    Atlanta, Savannah

To partition our store information by region using the list-partitioning method, i use the CREATE TABLE command, as seen here:

```
CREATE TABLE store_master
         ( Store_id                   NUMBER,
           Store_address              VARCHAR2(40),
           City                       VARCHAR2(30),
           State                      VARCHAR2(2),
           zip                        VARCHAR2(10),
           manager_id                 NUMBER   )
           PARTITION BY LIST (city)
           STORAGE(INITIAL 100k, NEXT 100k, PCTINCREASE 0)
           TABLESPACE store_data
            (
                PARTITION south_florida
                     VALUES ('MIAMI','ORLANDO')
                     STORAGE(INITIAL 100k, NEXT 100k, PCTINCREASE 0)
                     TABLESPACE store_data_south_florida,
                PARTITION north_florida
                     VALUES ('JACKSONVILLE','TAMPA', 'PENSACOLA')
                     STORAGE(INITIAL 100k, NEXT 100k, PCTINCREASE 0)
                     TABLESPACE store_data_north_florida,
                PARTITION south_georga
                     VALUES ('BRUNSWICK', 'WAYCROSS', 'VALDOSTA')
                     STORAGE(INITIAL 100k, NEXT 100k, PCTINCREASE 0)
                     TABLESPACE store_data_south_georga,
                PARTITION north_georgia
                     VALUES ('ATLANTA','SAVANNAH', NULL));
```

you can also see it here   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4
but i am getting this error ..

Schema Creation Failed: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

somebody please help.

Comment: Is all specified tablespaces already created? Is it mistype in `TABLESPACE store_data_south_georga` (instead of `store_data_south_georgIa`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage at table level should be above PARTITION BY clause. Partitions inherit table-level storage parameters, so it is not necessary to specify it again (unless they are different for a partition). Also storage parameters are not comma separated.

This should work:

```
CREATE TABLE store_master
         ( Store_id                   NUMBER,
           Store_address              VARCHAR2(40),
           City                       VARCHAR2(30),
           State                      VARCHAR2(2),
           zip                        VARCHAR2(10),
           manager_id                 NUMBER   )
           STORAGE(INITIAL 100k NEXT 100k PCTINCREASE 0)
           TABLESPACE store_data
           PARTITION BY LIST (city)
            (
                PARTITION south_florida
                     VALUES ('MIAMI','ORLANDO')
                     TABLESPACE store_data_south_florida,
                PARTITION north_florida
                     VALUES ('JACKSONVILLE','TAMPA', 'PENSACOLA')
                     TABLESPACE store_data_north_florida,
                PARTITION south_georga
                     VALUES ('BRUNSWICK', 'WAYCROSS', 'VALDOSTA')
                     TABLESPACE store_data_south_georga,
                PARTITION north_georgia
                     VALUES ('ATLANTA','SAVANNAH', NULL));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i am new in Toad so i am not aware of this type of operation so while using toad i am giving the name of store data tablespace first and then it is asking me  for the data files.so in the data files list i am giving the names of the subtablespaces i.e store_data_south_florida and so on.. am i correct??

Comment: Watch out for terminology. Data file is physical, while tablespace is a logical construct. Tablespace at table level specified where the data is stored for nonpartitioned tables. For partitioned tables it specifies the default tablespace to use, although it can be overriden at partition level. Here north_georgia will use tablespace store_data, whereas remaining partitions will use the tablespaces specified in PARTITION clauses.

Comment: OK i understand your explanation ,it it nice.But here you told me about physical  data file.So from where i will specify physical data files??

Comment: You can specify data files when creating/altering tablespaces. Take a look at [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/physical.htm#CNCPT003)